# GCP Cloud Function gets 403 when calling get_bucket for GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I have a cloud function with the basic code below that is trying to get blobs in a gcs bucket.

```
import base64
import json
import functions_framework

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

# Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def hello_pubsub(cloud_event):
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(some_bucket)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=file, delimiter='/')
    print(blobs)
```

However, after the function runs, I get a 403 error with message `google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/aRandomBucket?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: abc123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."`

I have given my cloud function service account Storage Admin and custom roles that include `storage.buckets.get` permission for accessing storage, and I've gone as far as opening the bucket to the public, but I still get a 403.

Below are images of the service account details - the `CloudFuncsStorageAndBQ` role just has `storage.buckets.get
[image: Picture of cloud function details]

[image: Picture of service account in IAM]

Comment: When you talk about your "Cloud Function service account", what it is? Did you explicitly deploy your function with a service account email? If no, can you share the "pattern" of the service account name that you have granted?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere added edits to the question to include images - the cloud function uses the default service account in the images, which I edited the roles and permissions of in IAM

Comment: Hmm wait, the 403 is not about Cloud Storage!! It's about you!! Your request to Cloud Functions is unauthenticated. In the permissions tab, make the function public to be able to invoke it. Or use the curl to perform an authenticated call

Comment: Something like that: `curl 
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    "https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction"`

Comment: Good call! It was the permissions to the cloud function, not GCS. However, I get a different 403 now that specifically states `storage.bucket.get` is forbidden

Comment: Are the function and the bucket in the same project?

Comment: Yes, function and bucket are in the same project, and both have the correct access to allUsers in addition to the service account's access.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - for anyone else who is struggling with this, I was using the wrong string for the bucket name, so I was accessing a bucket that didn't exist.